# Generate insert statement with the data from another table dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to create the stored procedure and generate insert statement for the table dynamically. The input parameters for the stored procedure are supposed to be `schema, table name, @col1, @col2, ..., @colN`. This stored procedure is supposed to take 1 random record from another server and based on this record is supposed to generate INSERT statement. `@col1, @col2, ..., @colN` parameters are optional in case you would like to overwrite original value with the one you need.

The insert record is supposed to look like that:

```
INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name VALUES (
col1,
col2,
...,
colN)
VALUES (
COALESCE(@col1, 'col1_value'),
COALESCE(@col2, 'col2_value'),
...,
COALESCE(@colN, 'colN_value')
);
```

Currently I can not realize how to take the real data and put it to the statement. What I already did is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateSampleDataInsertSP
    @SchemaName VARCHAR(255),
    @TableName VARCHAR(255)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @columns VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @columnsWithCoalesce VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT  c.name
INTO    #column
FROM    sys.tables t
        JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
        JOIN sys.types tt ON c.system_type_id = tt.system_type_id
WHERE   t.name = @TableName
        AND s.name = @SchemaName
        AND tt.name NOT IN ( 'timestamp' );


SET @columns = NULL; 
SELECT  @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ', ', '') + name
FROM    #column;

SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 ' + @columns + ' FROM AnotherDatabase.' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' ORDER BY NEWID();';



SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + '] (' + @columns + ') VALUES ();';

SELECT  @sql;
```

I do not care about ideal code or solution. I need result and that's it.

UPDATED:

-- **Example #1**

```
USE tempdb
GO

/*CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateSampleDataInsertSP ...*/

CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee (ID INT, EmployeeName VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee VALUES (1, 'John Smith');

EXEC dbo.GenerateSampleDataInsertSP @SchemaName = 'dbo', @TableName = 'Employees';

------------------------ EXPECTED OUTPUT OF THE PROCEDURE (NOT THE ACTION, BUT PLAIN TEXT) ------------------

INSERT INTO dbo.Employee
(
 ID,
 EmployeeName
)
VALUES
(
 COALESCE(@ID, '1'), 
 COALESCE(@EmployeeName, 'John Smith') 
);
```

-- **Example #2**

```
USE tempdb
GO

/*CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateSampleDataInsertSP ...*/

CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders (ID INT, OrderNbr VARCHAR(10), OrderDate DATE, CustomerID ID);

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders VALUES (7, '12345678', GETDATE(), 1024);

EXEC dbo.GenerateSampleDataInsertSP @SchemaName = 'dbo', @TableName = 'Orders';

------------------------ EXPECTED OUTPUT OF THE PROCEDURE (NOT THE ACTION, BUT PLAIN TEXT) ------------------

INSERT INTO dbo.Orders 
(
  ID,
  OrderNbr,
  OrderDate,
  CustomerId
)
VALUES
(
  COALESCE(@ID, '7'),
  COALESCE(@OrderNbr,'12345678'),
  COALESCE(@OrderDate, '2015-07-05'),
  COALESCE(@CustomerId, '1024')
);
```

Comment: You need to convert everything to strings, check the datatypes from sys.columns so that you add 's to *char fields and  most likely you'll need to specify suitable format for date / time fields in addition to 's. Identity fields must be skipped too. But there's probably ready made code / tools / other options to do this...

Comment: You might want to search for more information on "quirky update" before depending on it to assemble comma delimited strings. The XML based approach in Dan Guzman's answer is reliable.

Comment: I modified the question with the examples

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll answer my own question. As I said that I do not care about the code beauty and performance, I just need the result so anyone who would provide more elegant solution would be accepted as solved solution. Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GenerateSampleDataInsertSP
    @SchemaName VARCHAR(255),
    @TableName VARCHAR(255)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  name
            FROM    tempdb.sys.tables
            WHERE   name LIKE '%##record%' )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##record;
END;
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @columns VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
    @columnsWithCoalesce VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT  c.name
INTO    #column
FROM    sys.tables t
        JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
        JOIN sys.types tt ON c.system_type_id = tt.system_type_id
WHERE   t.name = @TableName
        AND s.name = @SchemaName
        AND tt.name NOT IN ( 'timestamp' );


SET @columns = NULL; 
SELECT  @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ', ', '') + name
FROM    #column;

SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 1 ' + @columns + ' INTO ##record FROM AnotherDataBase.' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' ORDER BY NEWID();';

EXEC (@sql);

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + '] (' + @columns + ') VALUES (';

DECLARE @columnsCur CURSOR, @ColumnName VARCHAR(255), @tmpValue VARCHAR(MAX), @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000);
SET @columnsCur = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM #column;
OPEN @columnsCur;
FETCH NEXT
FROM @columnsCur INTO @ColumnName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT @value=CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM ##record;'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, N'@value VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @value=@tmpValue OUTPUT
    SET @sql = @sql + 'COALESCE(@'+ @ColumnName +', ''' + @tmpValue + '''),';
    FETCH NEXT
FROM @columnsCur INTO @ColumnName;
END;
CLOSE @columnsCur;
DEALLOCATE @columnsCur;


SET @sql = @sql + ');'

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, ',);', ');');

SELECT  @sql;

GO
```

Comment: Column names with problem characters, e.g. spaces, will cause some issues. Adding brackets around all of the entity names will only get you so far, using column names to create variable names will fail.

Comment: In my case I can ignore that, we do not have names like that. Anyway even if we have that I can fix the script manually in that case.